# Using a drop down menu in Vue to change color of text

Tags: vue.js, drop-down-menu, vuejs2, vue-cli

I am trying to change the color of text depending on what option is chosen from a drop-down menu. This is for a TODO List project that I am working on. The drop-down menu has three options: High urgency (change text to red), Medium Urgency (change text to yellow), and Low Urgency (change text to green).

```
<template>
  <div class="TodoList">
    <input type="text" class="todo-input" v-model="newTodo" @keyup.enter="addTodo">
    <div v-for="(todo, index) in todos" :key="todo.id" class="todo-item"     
        </div>
        <ul class="urgency-column">
            <li>
                <label class="todo-label" >Select Urgency level:</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <select class="todo-drop" id="" onchange="setUrgency()">
                    <option value="high">High Urgency</option>
                    <option value="medium">Medium Urgency</option>
                    <option value="low">Low Urgency</option>
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<scripts>
export default {
  methods: {
    setUrgency(todo) {}
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model) to capture the selected urgency. Make sure the model includes an `urgency` property when adding a new TODO item:

```js
methods: {
  addItem() {
    this.todos.push({
      urgency: '',
      //...
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="todo-drop" v-model="todo.urgency">...</select>
```

#### Class binding

You could use a [class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) to set a specific class based on the value of the item's `urgency` value:

```html
<div class="item-text"
     :class="{ high: todo.urgency === 'high', medium: todo.urgency === 'medium', low: todo.urgency === 'low' }">
  {{todo.text}}
</div>
```

Then in your `<style>` block, style the item's text according to the corresponding urgency class:

```css
.item-text.high {
  color: red;
}
.item-text.medium {
  color: yellow;
}
.item-text.low {
  color: green;
}
```

[image: Edit Conditional styles in Vue (2)]

#### Attribute binding

Or you could apply an attribute that could be selected in CSS. For example, this adds to the TODO item's text container an `urgency` attribute with a value equal to the selected urgency:

```html
<div class="item-text" :urgency="todo.urgency">{{todo.text}}</div>
```

Then in your `<style>` block, use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to style the item text by urgency:

```css
.item-text[urgency="high"] {
  color: red;
}
.item-text[urgency="medium"] {
  color: yellow;
}
.item-text[urgency="low"] {
  color: green;
}
```

[image: Edit Conditional styles in Vue]